# console.writeline values of array on one line

Tags: c#

How to print Values of two arrays on one line ?

I have tried with this code

```
int[] arr1 = { 37, 45, 65 };
int[] arr2 = { 70, 89, 118 };

var myList = new List<int>();
myList.AddRange(arr1);
myList.AddRange(arr2);
int[] arr3 = myList.ToArray();
Console.WriteLine("Combined array elements..");
foreach (int res in arr3)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" " + res + " ");
}
```

Comment: Just replace `Console.WriteLine` with `Console.Write`

Comment: You don't even have to create a `List<int>` or use `.ToArray()`. Use `foreach (int res in arr1.Concat(arr2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create a new array, just [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netframework-4.8) the two arrays and then use `Write` instead of `WriteLine`:

```
foreach(var res in arr1.Concat(arr2)
{
  Console.Write($"{res} ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks all  :)        I will take a look at all the solutions

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Console.Write` or

```
string str;
foreach (int res in arr3)
{
    str += $"{res} ";
}
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

In this case, if the array is large you should use `StringBuilder`

But the best way to do this seems to me like this:

```
int[] arr1 = { 37, 45, 65 };
int[] arr2 = { 70, 89, 118 };
Console.Write(String.Join(" ", arr1.Concat(arr2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr1 = { 37, 45, 65 };
        int[] arr2 = { 70, 89, 118 };

        var myList = new List<int>();
        myList.AddRange(arr1);
        myList.AddRange(arr2);
        int[] arr3 = myList.ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine("Combined array elements..");
        foreach (int res in arr3)
        {
            Console.Write(" " + res + " ");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Write` instead of `WriteLine`, plus using `LINQ` for less code:

```
        int[] arr1 = { 37, 45, 65 };
        int[] arr2 = { 70, 89, 118 };
        Console.WriteLine("Combined array elements..");
        arr1.Concat(arr2).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.Write($"{x} "))
```

Comment: Thanks rad i will take look at it :)